# Proper use of class and dict from user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been struggling with my code for a class project and am in need of some help. I am not sure if I need to have a nested dictionary or list of dict or just use class in a list or dict. I've struggled to find the answers and could use some help with my code.

Should I just use list instead or am I thinking of this the right way, having the values stored in a dictionary or nested dict of some kind.

I'm especially at a loss for `menu==3 #delete an item` because as it is now I can only delete one attribute but what I need is to delete a whole property by property ID if possible

As you can probably tell I'm quite confused by now and would really appreciate any help from more experienced programmers.

```
inventory = {}

#class & constructor
class Property:  
    def __init__(self, propertyID, address, city, state, zipcode, squarefeet, modelname, salestatus):
        self.propertyID = propertyID
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.modelname = modelname
        self.squarefeet = squarefeet + 'Square Feet'
        self.salestatus = salestatus


def print_Property(o):
    if not isinstance(o, Property):
        raise TypeError('print_Property(): requires a Property')
    print('The property selected is Property ID: {} located at {} {} {} The Sqare footage is {}, {} model, Current status: {}'. format(o.propertyID,o.addresss, o.city, o.state, o.zipcode, o.squarefeet, o.modelname, o.salestatus))  

def main():
    print('What would you like to do today?')
    print('----------------------------------------')
    print('1. Add a new item to the Inventory')
    print('2. Update an Existing item in the Inventory')
    print('3. Delete an existing item from the Inventory')
    print('4. View the current item inventory')
    print('5. Print the Inventory to a text file')
    print('------------------------------')
    while True:
        try:
            menu = int(input('Type a number 1-5'))    

            if menu == 1: #Add data
              print('Add a new property to the inventory...')

              propertyID = input('Enter the property Listing ID:') #User inputting a property ID
              inventory['Property ID']= propertyID

              address = input('Enter the property address:') #User inputting an address
              inventory['Address']= address

              city = input('Enter property city:') #User inputting a city
              inventory['City']= city

              state = input('Enter property state:') #User inputting a state
              inventory['State']= state

              zipcode = int(input('Enter the property zipcode:')) #User inputting a zipcode
              inventory['Zipcode']= zipcode

              modelname = input('Enter property model name:') #User inputting a property model name
              inventory['Model Name']= modelname

              squarefeet = int(input('Enter the sqaure footage of the property:')) #User inputting the sqaure footage for the property
              inventory['Square Footage']= squarefeet

              salestatus = input('Enter the property status:(Is the home sold, available, or under contract?):') #User inputting the property status
              inventory['Current Staus']= salestatus


              print('The following properties are in the inventory now:')
              print(inventory)
              #break

            elif menu == 2: #Update data
              print('Update an item from the inventory...')

              print (inventory)

              itemreplace = input("Enter the name of the attribute you wish to replace:")
              itemupdate = input("Enter the new information for that attribute now:")
              inventory[itemreplace]= itemupdate

              print(inventory)

            elif menu == 3: #Delete data
              print("Which property do you want to delete?")
              print(inventory)

              itemdel = input("Enter the Property ID of the property to delete.")
              if itemdel in inventory:
                del inventory[itemdel]

              print(inventory)

            elif menu == 4: #View data
              print(inventory)

            elif menu == 5: #Print data
              output = open("PropertyData.txt", "w")
              for item in inventory:
                output.write("%s\n" % item)
              print('Text file \'PropertyData.txt\' has been created.')

            else:
              print('That number is not valid. Please try 1-5.')

        except ValueError: #throw an error for anything that is not a number
              print('You may only select values 1-5. (ex.: 2)')

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 1):

@Lucas is right. Here is a fully working ( I think :) ) system:

```
import json

class Property:  
    def __init__(self, propertyID, address, city, state, zipcode, squarefeet, modelname, salestatus):
        self.propertyID = propertyID
        self.address = address
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.modelname = modelname
        self.squarefeet = squarefeet
        self._sqfeet_description = str(squarefeet) + ' Square Feet'
        self.salestatus = salestatus

    def __str__(self):
        o = self
        return 'Property ID: {}. Address: {}, {}, {}, {}. Size: {} sq feet, {} model. Status: {}.'.format(o.propertyID,o.address, o.city, o.state, o.zipcode, o.squarefeet, o.modelname, o.salestatus)

    def as_json(self):
        return {x:y for x,y in self.__dict__.items() if not x.startswith("_")}

def int_input(prompt, range=None):
    while True:
        ans = input(prompt)
        if not ans.isnumeric():
            print("Please enter a valid number")
            continue

        ans = int(ans)
        if range == None:
            return ans

        if ans not in range:
            print(f"Please enter a number between {min(range)} and {max(range)}")
            continue

        return ans

inventory = []

def main():
    print('What would you like to do today?')
    print('----------------------------------------')
    print('1. Add a new item to the Inventory')
    print('2. Update an Existing item in the Inventory')
    print('3. Delete an existing item from the Inventory')
    print('4. View the current item inventory')
    print('5. Print the Inventory to a text file')
    print('------------------------------')
    while True:
        menu = int_input("Choose an option 1-5", range(1,6))
        if menu == 1:
            # add data
            propertyID = input('Enter the property Listing ID:') #User inputting a property ID
            address = input('Enter the property address:') #User inputting an address
            city = input('Enter property city:') #User inputting a city
            state = input('Enter property state:') #User inputting a state
            zipcode = int_input('Enter the property zipcode:') #User inputting a zipcode
            modelname = input('Enter property model name:') #User inputting a property model name
            squarefeet = int_input('Enter the sqaure footage of the property:') #User inputting the sqaure footage for the property
            salestatus = input('Enter the property status:(Is the home sold, available, or under contract?):') #User inputting the property status

            this_property = Property(
                propertyID,
                address,
                city,
                state,
                zipcode,
                squarefeet,
                modelname,
                salestatus)

            inventory.append(this_property)

            print('The following properties are in the inventory now:')
            print(*("\t" + str(i) for i in inventory), sep="\n")
            print()
        elif menu == 2:
            # update data
            while True:
                propertyID = input("Enter the property id: ")
                this_property = [x for x in inventory if x.propertyID == propertyID]
                if not this_property:
                    print("That property doesn't exist")
                    continue
                this_property = this_property[0]
                break

            lookup = {
                "propertyID": str,
                "address":str,
                "city":str,
                "state":str,
                "zipcode":int,
                "modelname":str,
                "squarefeet":int,
                "salestatus":str
            }

            while True:
                detail_name = input("Enter the detail you wish to change")
                if detail_name not in lookup:
                    print("That detail does not exist")
                    continue
                break

            if lookup[detail_name] == int:
                new = int_input("Enter the new value:")
            else:
                new = input("Enter the new value:")

            setattr(this_property, detail_name, new)
        elif menu == 3:
            # delete
            while True:
                propertyID = input("Enter the property id: ")
                this_property = [i for i, x in enumerate(inventory) if x.propertyID == propertyID]
                if not this_property:
                    print("That property doesn't exist")
                    continue
                this_property = this_property[0]
                break

            del inventory[this_property]
        elif menu == 4:
            # print inventory
            print('The following properties are in the inventory now:')
            print(*("\t" + str(i) for i in inventory), sep="\n")
            print()

        elif menu == 5:
            # save
            new_inv = [x.as_json() for x in inventory]
            with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
                json.dump(new_inv, f)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

If you want to save your properties and be able to load them again, add this method to `Property`:

```
class Property:

    ...

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_code):
        c = cls(*(None for _ in range(8)))

        for x,y in json_code.items():
            setattr(c, x, y)

        return c
```

and this function to the body of your program:

```
def load_from_file():
    with open("output.txt") as f:
        for item in json.load(f):
            inventory.append(Property.from_json(item))
```

and then call the function at the start:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_from_file()
    main()
```

(obviously make sure the file exists before that though - just save `[]` to `output.txt` before running the program for the first time)

Comment: Thanks so much! Seeing code in a functioning form really makes things more understandable as to where I made mistakes. Thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @JorinBecker Glad to have helped :) If this was useful, please upvote and accept :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use a list of `Property` objects, where each element in a list is an individual property. Adding properties to the inventory means creating a new object, filling in all the fields and appending it to the inventory list.

Comment: Thank you!That really helps